# selenium python script to check for occasional html element that sometimes appears on a webpage

Tags: python, html, selenium

i have a small selenium python script running and i run into a error sometimes on the page its working on

i am waiting for a modal pop up to appear and it processes things in the background, if all runs smothly everything is fine the script completes and loops again ok

very occasionaly on the modal popup we get a button appear that says to try again and we need to click it to try again

this 'try again' pop up buttonin the modal causes my script to hang

most of the time to page runs and the 'try again' button never appears

how would i test for the occurance of the 'try again' button when it occurs as a button in the modal

this is my code that hangs

```
    main_page = driver.current_window_handle
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(10) ###adjust this depending on your uplaod speed
            for handle in driver.window_handles:
                if handle != main_page:
                    login_page = handle
            driver.switch_to.window(login_page)
            css_and_click("button[class='button btn--rounded btn-primary btn--large']")
            driver.switch_to.window(main_page)
            break
        except Exception as wtf:
            #print(wtf)
            print("----- Waiting for metamask sign window -----")
            continue
```

the MINTING  'Try again' button the sometimes appears

```
<button data-step-confirm-button="true" type="button" data-marker="steps-modal/stepButton/Mint" class="sc-bdvvtL sc-gKclnd sc-iCfMLu sc-furwcr sc-kDTinF kMXwoE eehqFj iEbWpe dofCUO">Try again</button>
```

XPATHS

```
//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button


/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/buttonAS
```

Comment: You might try using a WebDriverListener: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverListener.html  (in beta)  Or the older, deprecated WebDriverEventListener: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html

Comment: @chloeharlow would you be able to provide with the website link to check?
Also, why absolute xpath instead of relative one?